# What is the complexity of the scheduler of the FreeRTOS?

Tags: freertos

I've searched through the documentation of FreeRTOS, but couldn't find anything related to the complexity of its scheduler. So, what is the complexity of it? Is there a way that I can detect it myself?

Comment: What do you mean by "complexity"?

Comment: @PMF I meant the time complexity.

Comment: You mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity ? There exist scheduling algorithms that work in linear time (of the number of tasks). I don't think using anything else would outweigh the polynomial cost.

Comment: @PMF Yes, I meant it. Anyway, it must have been documented, right?

Comment: Likely, yes. But you probably need to look for the scheduling concept/algorithm instead. From that, it's complexity might be obvious.

Comment: I would imagine it depends on many different variables.

Comment: @RealtimeRik Are those variables vary during runtime or fixed at compile time using the configuration macros? Which of them is the most obvious one?

Comment: There are literally millions of possible configuration combinations. What are you trying to achieve with this information?

Comment: @RealtimeRik I just wonder if there is a way to determine the time complexity. If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FreeRTOS kernel stores the TCB *(Task Control Block)* instance pointers in an array of doubly-linked lists. Indexes of the array represent the priority group that a task belongs to. Here is a visual diagram of it. Note that the list contains only the TCB's of tasks that are in the ready state.
[image: Illustration of FreeRTOS Ready Task List Data Structure]

Each time the scheduler runs, the algorithm selects the first TCB that is located at the highest index*(i.e. highest priority)* possible. If the doubly-linked list of the highest priority has multiple elements, then it selects the first one. A round-robin mechanism is used for this purpose. It is obvious that this process is independent of the count of the tasks which are ready to be scheduled. Therefore, the time complexity is **O(1)**.

Comment: I haven't studied the code, but according to your answer, pointers to ready and blocked tasks should be stored in separate lists. Otherwise the scheduler would need to scan all TCBs to determine if they are ready, and it would be O(n).

Comment: @Tagli Thanks for the warning. Yes, only the ones that are ready to be scheduled are stored inside the lists. I've edited the answer.